# Bootstrap Video Modal not showing with plyr plugin

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video, bootstrap-modal, plyr

I have a bootstrap modal that shows an html5 video fine; however, the moment I replace html5 video player with plyr plugin, the video does not show in the modal at all ? Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Please check code below:

HTML CODE:

```
<!--Modal: Name-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="product-video-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">

                <!--Content-->
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <!--Body-->
                    <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">

                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">









                           <video id="product-vid-src" class="embed-responsive-item " width="100%"   controls crossorigin playsinline  >
                              <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="720">



                          </video>






                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!--Footer-->
                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                        <span class="mr-4">Spread the word!</span>
                        <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <!--Twitter-->
                        <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <!--Google +-->
                        <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-gplus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <!--Linkedin-->
                        <a type="button" class="btn-floating btn-sm btn-ins"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>

                        <button type="button" class="closeBut btn btn-outline-primary btn-rounded btn-md ml-4" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>



                    </div>





                </div>
                <!--/.Content-->

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Modal: Name-->
```

The javascript and jquery code are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// snippet for plyr plugin          
const player = new Plyr('video', {captions: {active: true}});
window.player = player;




 $('#product-video-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var product_vid = document.getElementById("product-vid-src");
    if (product_vid != null) {
      product_vid.pause();
      product_vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  });
  })
      </script>
```

The moment I remove "snippet for plyr plugin" as commented above, the HTML5 plugin works fine and shows on the modal without any issues?

Any input would be much appreciated 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by doing the following:

1 - remove the following class

```
embed-responsive
```

2- Adjust padding on

```
.embed-responsive-16by9 {

  padding-bottom:0;

}
```